# Flexbox space-around except at left and right border

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following scenario:

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 75px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  
  line-height: 75px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
</ul>
```

http://codepen.io/HugoGiraudel/pen/LklCv

I want one thing changed:
The left and right divs should not have a space between the parent div and itself.

When I do `justify-content: space-between`, that problem is solved but then the divs are no longer centered.

Comment: No...you can't do that with flexbox. The justify-content applies **per row**, so once the element wraps the second row justifies it's **own** content.

Comment: you could try adding some empty divs to compensate

Comment: Ye the row wrap doens't seem to be working in Firefox. I looked at it in Chrome. Add this for Firefox: flex-wrap:wrap;

Comment: @maioman That's a horrible suggestion and where would you put them?

Comment: @Paulie_D obiouvsly at the end of the list, the point is making the right calculation with js on how many are needed

Comment: Putting them at the end won't center as required.

Comment: @maioman I'm not going to use JS for this.

Comment: @Paulie_D Well I guess it can't be done indeed. Thanks anyway.